# Managed Package: Get test coverage for already uploaded 1gp package version

Tags: managed-package, code-coverage

Is there any way to get test coverage for already uploaded version of 1gp package?

E.g. for 2gp each successful package version creation returns in response coverage percentage and also it can be query at any point in the future from Package2 object.

Is there something similar for 1gp package? Cause it looks weird to run all tests after upload just to get coverage stats.

Answer (score 1):

## Not Directly

That was one of the limitations of the 1GP model. You had to run all tests as part of the upload process (to tell if you hit 75% coverage), and that data was later just discarded, as far as I can tell. You can, however, install the package to a fresh org (such as a Scratch Org), and do a Run All Tests there. This is obviously not ideal, but there were a lot of limitations with packages back in the day, which is why 2GP was such a big deal.